# Set theory Transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We say that a set $A$ is transitive if whenever $y\in $ and $x\in A$, it follows that $y\in A$. Determine if each of the following sets is transitive:

1. $\emptyset$
2. $\{\emptyset\}$

Solutions:

1. Since $\emptyset$ has no elements, $\emptyset$ is transitive. (The statement “whenever $x\in\emptyset$ and $y\in x$, it follows that $y\in\emptyset$” is true simply because “$x\in\emptyset$” is always false. In this case, we say that the statement is vacuously true.)
2. The only element of $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\emptyset$, and $y\in\emptyset$ is always false. So, $\{\emptyset\}$ is transitive.

My questions:

1. Why “$x\in\emptyset$“ is always false?
2. And why “$y\in\emptyset$” is always false?

Comment: You ask why "$x\in\emptyset$ is always false"... Because that is the defining characteristic of what the empty set is.  The empty set is the set which has no elements.  The same can be said if you were to use a different variable name instead (*e.g. $y\in\emptyset$ is also false for all $y$*)

Comment: One answer to your single question: Because nothing is a member of $\emptyset$. Surely you already know that -- you had to have typed "\emptyset" to write the symbol. So I can't understand why you're asking. Maybe you're confused by the vacuously true implications (if $p$ is false then $p\rightarrow q$ is always true).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the empty set $\emptyset$ is the set with no element. The statement $x \in \emptyset$, if true, would imply that the empty set has an element, which is false by definition. Similarly, $y \in \emptyset$ is a false statement.

Comment: Why (i)  “ø” is transitive ? Could you explain it a little more

Comment: The exercise above defined a set $A$ to be transitive if $y\in x$ and $x \in A$ implies that $y \in A$. 
The empty set is transitive because of the following reason:
Suppose this statement was false, that is, suppose there exist $x,y$ such that $y \in x$ and $x \in \emptyset$ but $y \not\in\emptyset$. This statement then implies that there exists $x$ such that $x \in \emptyset$ which is false because the empty set has no element. 
As the statement being false leads to a contradiction, it must be true.

Comment: How  can ∅ be  transitive if it has no elements ?

Comment: Notice that the definition of transitivity expressly states that whenever $y \in x$ and $x \in A, $ then $y \in A$. However, if the empty set has no elements, then there is no way to falsify this statement. It is not possible to find a $y \in x$ and $x \in \emptyset$ such that $y \not\in \emptyset$ simply because such an $x$ cannot exist (By definition of the empty set).

Comment: I still don’t  get it. 

It is not possible to find a ∈
y
∈
x
 and ∈∅
x
∈
∅
 such that ∉∅
y
∉
∅
 simply because such an 
x
 cannot exist (By definition of the empty set). 

Could you elaborate more?

Comment: We need to look at what it means to say that a set is "not" transitive. If we negate the given definition, we say that a set $A$ is not transitive if there exists some set $x$ and element $y$ such that $y \in x$ and $x \in A$ but $y \not\in A$. Refer to [this](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_propositional.html) to learn more about why this is the negation of the above statement. 

Now, if a statement is not false, it must be true (by the [Principles of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)). Now, if we take our $A$ as the empty set, can we find $x$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137806/discussion-between-chirag-kar-and-guilherme-woolley).

Comment: How ∉∅ implies that  there  exist x suck  ∈∅ ?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley where did you get the idea that $y\notin \emptyset$ implies there exists an $x$ such that $x\in \emptyset$???  No one ever suggested such a thing.  That statement is blatantly false... there are no elements in the emptyset.

Comment: A set $X$ (*empty or otherwise*) is considered transitive by definition whenever **if** any set $x$ contained as an element of $X$ (*if any even exist in the first place*) are such that elements of that $x$ (*if any even exist in the first place*) are also elements of $X$.  The whole punchline here in this exercise is to be able to read between the lines and recognize those "*if any even exist in the first place*" phrases and to understand that no elements existing satisfying those conditions does not preclude the set from being considered transitive.

Comment: What is “any even”?

Comment: What is your native language?  If it is not English then you need to be asking someone who speaks your native language explain this to you.  By "*if any even exist in the first place*"...it means the same as "*if any exist in the first place*" but with the heavy emphasis on the fact that there might not exist any and that is a fine and expected result.

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley merriam webster dictionary entry for [even](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even).  Read the entry for the adverb meaning of "even."

Comment: x
∈
∅
 and ∈
y
∈
x
, it follows that ∈∅
y
∈
∅
” is true simply because “∈∅
x
∈
∅
” is always false





this is what is  confusing  me it first says r ∈∅
x
∈
∅
 is true,then it says r ∈∅
x
∈
∅
 is always false..

Comment: Separate in your mind the following:  the *premise*, the *conclusion*, and the *implication*.  The premise here is "$x\in X$ and $y\in x$".  The conclusion is "$y\in X$".  The implication is the entirety of the phrase "*if $x\in X$ and $y\in x$ then $y\in X$*".  We are not saying the conclusion is true.  We are saying the **implication** is true.  That is a very different thing than saying the conclusion is true.  Here, since the premise is false, regardless of whether or not the conclusion is true or false the implication is considered true.

Comment: With the premise "$x\in \emptyset$ and $y\in x$", since that premise is always false (*because it is impossible to have $x\in \emptyset$*) no matter what the conclusion was the implication of "*if $x\in \emptyset$ and $y\in x$ then ____anything____*" is considered true.  That is a vacuous truth, as was alluded to in the original comments.  Again... **no one is saying the conclusion is true**.  No one is saying that there exists some $y\in \emptyset$.  We are however saying that the *implication* is true.

Comment: Could you explain more  about why the premisse been false the implication is vacuous truth

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley we are saying that suppose that we assume that a condition called P is true, and P implies that some event Q happens. If we cannot satisfy P, we cannot say that “P implies Q” is false. I quote directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth): (next comment)

Comment: the statement "_all cell phones in the room are turned off_" will be true when no cell phones are in the room. In this case, the statement "_all cell phones in the room are turned on_" would **also** be vacuously true, as would the statement which merges them: "_all cell phones in the room are turned on and turned off_", which would otherwise (i,e, if some cell phones were there in the room) be incoherent and false. For that reason, it is sometimes said that a statement is vacuously true because it does not really say anything.

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley for another example, the statement “_if  Porto Allegre is in France, then Rio de Janeiro is in Bolivia_” is **also true**. This is just because we cannot say that it is false, that we define it to be vacuously true.

Comment: the statement "all cell phones in the room are turned off" will be true when no cell phones are in the room. 
The cells are turned off when no cell phones are in the room? I Can’t understand

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley can you prove that "all cell phones in the room are turned off" is false when no cell phones are there in the room? You can’t, so you just _accept_ it as a vacuous truth.

Comment: I still don’t get it

Comment: Is true and false when  "all cell phones in the room are turned off"?